# Get SID & RID using strophe.js

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

How can I get the SID & RID when connecting to a XMPP server using strophejs ? I am using Ejabbered as the XMPP server.

Here is my code

```
        $(document).bind('connect', function (ev, data) {

        var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://localhost:5280/http-bind');

        conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {
            if (status === Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {

                $(document).trigger('connected');
            } else if (status === Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
                $(document).trigger('disconnected');
            }
        });

        Gab.connection = conn;
    });

$(document).bind('connected', function () {
    ---------------------------------
    ---------------------------------

    console.log(Gab.connection.jid); // Got jid
    console.log(Gab.connection.rid); // Value is undefined
    console.log(Gab.connection.sid); // value is undefined
});
```

I have tried the above code. But getting undefined as value.

I have checked this question, 
[XMPP: retrieving BOSH Session ID and RID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438175/xmpp-retrieving-bosh-session-id-and-rid#)

but in the comments there, 'undefined' is the result!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get the RID and SID from my strophe connection by adding a function to connection.xmlOutput. This gives the ability to view the outgoing stanza's before they're sent. Here is an example:

```
      connection.xmlOutput = function (e) {
        if (IS_CONNECTED) {

            LAST_USED_RID = $(e).attr('rid');
            LAST_USED_SID = $(e).attr('sid');
            log(' XMLOUTPUT INFO - OUTGOING RID=' + LAST_USED_RID + ' [SID=' + LAST_USED_SID + ']');
            //log(' XMLOUTPUT INFO - OUTGOING XML = \n'+e.outerHTML);
            //set some variables to keep track of our rid and sid
        }
    };
```

You may also be able to access the RID and SID properties from connection's `._proto`, ex:

```
connection._proto.rid
```

This may be related: https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js/issues/180