# Rails, BOSH, XMPP should I manually increase rid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmpp, strophe

I have installed ejabberd on my system and gems 'xmpp4r', 'ruby_bosh'. I'm trying to make a chat client using strophejs in my views. Now I'm getting jid, sid and rid with BOSH and can save them in session using in view after this all.
So I'm connecting strophejs to http-bind like

```
var connection = new Strophe.Connection('http://localhost:5280/http-bind/');
```

and trying to attach my session like

```
connection.attach("#{bosh_session_jid}", "#{bosh_session_id}", "#{bosh_session_random_id}", function(status){
         console.log(status);
     });
```

bosh_session_jid, bosh_session_rid and bosh_session_sid are this identifiers that I should use and they are not changed.

So, at first connection attempt everything is connected and working ok and I even can send message. But after window reloading (F5 I mean) it's trying to reconnect and reattach process and sends me

```
POST http://localhost:5280/http-bind/ 404 (Not Found)
```

I read "Professional XMPP programming with JS and jQuery" and found line

```
Each subsequent request increments the RID by one.
```

So, do I need to increase rid by 1 in my cookies after each attach? Or then? Or I don't need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must increment the RID yourself when refreshing or changing pages. I increment by 1 when loading the new page before attaching. Note: if you are storing in a cookie, you should update with every call returned with the new RID, so that your cookie is updated with the most current RID.

Comment: only before attaching (after connecting you mean?) ? I don't need to update RID after sending messages or smth? Is RID increase number is important (I mean if somehow it will be increased by 2, will I get an error) ?

Comment: I was referring to keeping track of the value of the RID in your cookie or however you are storing it. You do not need to increment the RID itself as long as you are not changing pages. Strophe will handle that for you.

Comment: Also, if increased less than 5, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, now I see that Strophy changes it. But the answer is - when this value is incremented? on each operation (connect, attach, send)? Because I need to update session variable that stores RID after each changing, to be sure that after reloading page user will be able to connect.

Comment: Each. Whenever a callback is made, update your cookie with the latest value. When you change pages, grab the value from your cookie before attaching and increment, then attach.

Comment: I've found why I have problems. As I can see in chrome dev tools in network tab, strophejs pings system every few seconds and each ping increases rid in connection._proto.rid. So now I need to find way to make a callback to increase rid on every ping

Comment: in strophe, find _processRequest. Add a call to your func that will update your RID tracker where you see "if (this.xmlOutput !== Strophe.Connection.prototype.xmlOutput)"

Comment: @AKovtunov, you may find the following answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25247139/2686738

Comment: Thank you guys. It's nearly working. I'm updating rid every request and it is saved. But if my page is working for a some time (let it be 5 mins) rid is increased by ~200. After this it saves OK, but after page reload I can't connect with strophejs. Just POST http://localhost:5280/http-bind/ 404 (Not Found) . Seems like it's waiting another rid.
If I'm updating page in ~1 min it will be working ok with prev. saved rid.

Comment: What's the strophe rid compared to your cookie rid value? they should match.